# Rails Metaprogramming: where is this gem installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming, bundler

Quick metaprogramming question. In my rails 5 project, I'd like to find the installed location of a certain gem in code (ie. not command line).

I started with `Bundler.install_path`.

Looking under that, I see all the versions of the various gems I have installed for this ruby (I use rbenv, but this should work for rvm too).

`/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/mygem-7eafb06c791d/`
`/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/mygem-3da2bf38d01a/`

`...and so on`

Is there a way to tell Bundler "Can you tell me the directory where the gem `mygem` is installed? Or if there was a hash of gem names with their directories (or something like that), that's fine too.

bonus: if there's a guide to the inner workings of bundler, that'd be cool too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundler has the `show` command to show the location of a gem:

`bundle show mygem`

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the Bundler source code based on this answer to get what I need. :>

Answer (score 0):

rbenv-bundler is plugin that makes the rbenv shims Bundler-aware so you dont' have to type bundler exec in front of every command. 
you can manage setting of the bundler with create a config file inside ~/.bundle/config (mac / linux)

```
BUNDLE_PATH: ~/vendor/some_path
```

if you need more information about config the bundler you can check [this bundler.io link](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-config.1.html)